# Incorrect Disk space usage in Linux server

Tags: linux, hard-drive, hardware, centos6

I can see the used disk quota on server is 81G for partition /dev/sda3 mounted to '/' as follows.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3       106G   81G   20G  81% /
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1       477M   52M  400M  12% /boot
tmpfs           1.0G     0  1.0G   0% /var/lib/mysqltmp
/usr/tmpDSK     4.0G  183M  3.6G   5% /tmp
```

But when Iam checking with the '/' directory by executing du -sh command it is taking only 17G of disk space, can any one advice where this remaining space is utilized, any advice ? Iam using CentOS release 6.7 (Final)

Comment: +1 for duplicate. That question has already most likely answer: `lsof | grep deleted`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe processes have open handles on large files (like a dropped database).
files may then seem deleted but space is not reclamined before all handles on these files are closed.

lsof may be your friend here.